# Is using Object.$method() functions standardized shorthand to refer to static (class) methods?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For example, looking at the Vue framework, there is extensive use of methods defined with $ like `Vue.$emit()` and `Vue.$on()`.

For example, here is the [source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/instance/events.js) for the events page in Vue:

```
Vue.prototype.$emit = function (event: string): Component {
    // ...
}
```

Is this standard practice or is this something particular to Vue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a framework specific naming convention and is not language related or have any special meaning within the language

`$` is a valid prefix for property or variable names and can be used any time

---

Simple example

```js
const $obj = {
  $1: 1,
  $2: 2
}

console.log($obj)
```

Comment: It's being used as a *prefix* here, not a suffix.

Comment: Suffice to say that `$` is a valid character in variable names. You can have it in the beginning, middle or end of the variable name.